# Explanation of why Neural Networks are non convex

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Why having a symmetry of values for the hidden state imply that the neural network is non convex? I could not find an intuitive answer for this yet.

Also, if we consider a Fully Connected network wtih ReLU non linearity(which is convex) then it is a composition of convex functions and ReLU is also non decreasing. Still the overall optimization problem becomes non convex.

Answer (score 1):

First, I give a simple proof why neural networks are non-convex. Then, I talk about the symmetry argument.

For simplicity, consider a two-layer MLP without bias, which can be written as $f(x) = W_2\sigma(W_1x)$. Assuming ReLU activation functions, $\sigma(\cdot)=\max\{\cdot, 0\}$ and thus, $\sigma$ is convex in $W_1$, as the $\max$ preserves convexity. Now, if $W_2$ is constant, then $f(x)$ is convex in $W_1$. Same, if $\sigma(W_1x)$ is constant, $f(x)$ is convex in $W_2$. However, $f(x)$ is not convex in both, $W_1 $ and $W_2$.

To see this, we simplify the problem even further and assume a one-dimensional input $x \in \mathbb{R}$, just one hidden-layer neuron with weight $w_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, and one output neuron with weight $w_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. W.l.g., we also assume $x > 0$, but the $x < 0$ case can be constructed similarly. First, we rewrite $f(x)=f(w_1, w_2) = f(w)$, with $w=(w_1, w_2)$ as we are interested in the fact if $f$ is convex w.r.t. $w$ given fixed $x$. By definition, $f$ is convex w.r.t. $w$, if $$f(tw+(1-t)w') \le tf(w) + (1-t)f(w')$$ for any two $w, w' \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $t \in [0,1]$.

We construct a case where this inequality is violated. Consider the choice $w=(0, 1)$, then $f(w)=0$ and $w'=(1,0)$, then again $f(w')=0$. Thus, any point $w''(t)=tw+(1-t)w'$ on the line segment joining $w$ and $w'$, is not allowed to have a function value larger than $0$ for convexity to hold, as $tf(w) + (1-t)f(w')=0$ for any $t$. Now consider the point $w''(t=0.5)=(0.5, 0.5)$ on the line segment. It has a function value $f(w'') = 0.5\cdot 0.5x = 0.25x > 0$ and thus, $f$ is not convex w.r.t. both $w_1$ and $w_2$.

---

Regarding the symmetry argument: It states that if I have multiple hidden layers and found a local minimum, I can "swap" neurons (weights) without effecting the function value, and thus create a different local minimal solution conflicting with convexity. However, this argument is incomplete as convex functions can have multiple local minima, which are then all global minima. Only strictly convex functions have a unique global minimum. Thus, this argument only rules out that our function is strictly convex. So one would need to show that on the line segment (in parameter space) between the two found minima, our function value increases again, as we did in the above proof.

Answer (score 0):

From the CV thread [Cost function of neural network is non-convex?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106334/cost-function-of-neural-network-is-non-convex/106343#106343):

> How does this relate to our neural network? A cost function $J(W,b)$
> has also a number of local maxima and minima, as you can see in [this
> picture](http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/09_Neural_Networks_Learning_files/Image%20%5B35%5D.png),
> for example.
>
> The fact that $J$ has multiple minima can also be interpreted in a
> nice way. In each layer, you use multiple nodes which are assigned
> different parameters to make the cost function small. Except for the
> values of the parameters, these nodes are the same. So you could
> exchange the parameters of the first node in one layer with those of
> the second node in the same layer, and accounting for this change in
> the subsequent layers. You'd end up with a different set of
> parameters, but the value of the cost function can't be distinguished
> by (basically you just moved a node, to another place, but kept all
> the inputs/outputs the same).

---

From [NonConvexity of neural networks](https://amartya18x.github.io/post/nn_nonconvex/):

> I don’t remember where I heard this arguement but it was a
> pretty interesting one and I couldn’t remember the entire
> reasoning and so as I began to think about it, I figured some of it
> out and I believe it is pretty reasonable. We have all argued that
> neural networks are difficult to optimize  because they are
> non-convex(or non-concave) for that matter. What we don’t talk
> about so much is why is it that they are non-convex. It probably has
> simpler answers where you will argue something about the
> non-linearities involved. This post has to do with a much more
> interesting answer.
>
> To understand the reasoning, we have to argue that if the function has
> atleast two local minimas such that their mid-point is not a local
> minima, the function is non-convex. In formal terms, $$\text{If
> > }\exists x,y \in Dom(f) \hspace{5pt }s.t.\hspace{5pt} g(x) = g(y) = 0
> > $$ and $$\forall z\in [x,y] \text{ s.t. } g(z) \neq 0  $$ where $g(x)$
> is a subgradient at $x$ the function is non-convex.
>
> This is pretty simple to follow from the Mid-point value theorem and
> the definition of convexity.
>
> Consider a neural network  $F(\cdot)$ with a few layers and name three
> layers $L_1, L_2$ and $ L_3$ Consider nodes $a$ and $b$ in $L_1$ and
> $c$ and $d$ in $L_2$.Let the parameters connecting node $i$ to $j$ be
> called $w_{ij}$.
>
> Thee arguement to the function can be thought of as $A=[\cdots w_{ac},
> > w_{ad}, \cdots , w_{bc}, w_{bd}\cdots]$ and the function evaluation as
> $f(A)$. Consider $B=[\cdots w_{ad}, w_{ac},\cdots, w_{bd}, w_{bc}, 
> > \cdots]$. I can claim that there exists a $B$ i.e. where $ w_{ad},
> > w_{ac}$ and $ w_{bd},  w_{bc} $  are swapped respectively, there
> exists an ordering of the other weights(permute the other edges) such
> that the function evaluation remains same. It is pretty easy to see
> how it can be true.
>
> Look at the following picture where the reg edges come into one node
> and the green into another.
>
> [image: before]
>
> For reference consider
>
> - The first red edge coming out of the top left node as $w_{ac}$
> - The gree edge out of the same node as $w_{ad}$.
> - The red edge out of the second node in the same layer as  $w_{bc}$
> - The green edge out of the second node as   $ w_{bd} $.
>
> Connect all edges coming in to $L_2$ from $L_1$ into node $d$ to node
> $c$ and vice versa and then shift the origin of  all outgoing edges
> from node $c$ to $L_3$ to node $d$ and vice versa. What you have
> acheived is the network that you would have achieved by holding the
> two nodes by your hand and manually exchanging their positions while
> keeping the connecting edges intact. And Voila! now you have $A, B \in
> > dom(F)$ where $F(A) = F(B) $.
>
> Now look at them after the edges are shifted.
>
> [image: after]
>
> [..]What this effectively means is that if the neural network was
> indeed convex, there would be a value which could be given to all
> nodes in a layer and yet the network would have represented a local
> optima. This is higly absurd and is very apparent if you consider a
> classification network where the final outputs should not have the
> same value in all nodes given some value in the input layer(which is
> also a part of the function arguement).
>
> To generalize this to any neural network, you will have to look at the
> activation functions and their properties. The claim you will be
> trying to verify is that the average of two permutations of an optimal
> point need not be optimal.
> I guess this was an interesting read. A very interesting thing this
> says is that
>
> A neural network cannot have a unique optima if it has atleast two
> distinct node values in the same layer. Amazing , isn’t it ?